# How to let a function know that a specific input parameter is of ether value?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am currently trying to build a prototype for a simple Ethereum based Ebay - I know there are already solutions for it, it is just for learning purposes.

Currently I am lacking the understanding on how to pass in changing ether values into functions. For example when I want to post a new auction:

```
struct Auction{
    address owner;
    uint price;
    string describtion;
  }

  Auction[] public auctions;

  function createAuction(address _owner, uint256 _price, string _describtion) public{
    Auction memory _auction = Auction({
      owner: _owner,
      price: _price,
      describtion: _describtion
    });

    auctions.push(_auction);
  }
```

This is the output of an example auction in remix after calling the getter of the auctions array:

[image: Remix screenshot of generic auctions array output.]

When I am now adding a new auction, I can only hand it uint256 values, which makes the prices non-ether values. My question is, how can I let the function know that the price variable is of type ether?

---

PS. I tried to create a static global variable, which is of type ether and it gives me back the ether value in wei. But I still can't adapt this on how to give the function different ether values with each call.

```
 uint256 public auctionStartPrice = 0.015 ether;

      struct Auction{
    address owner;
    uint256 price;
    string describtion;
  }

  Auction[] public auctions;

  function createAuction(address _owner, string _describtion) public{
    Auction memory _auction = Auction({
      owner: _owner,
      price: auctionStartPrice,
      describtion: _describtion
    });

    auctions.push(_auction);
  }

  function getVAlueOfAuction(uint256 x) public returns (uint256 value){
      value = auctions[x].price;
      return value;
  }
```

Here is the output with the global variable as starting price:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, that the answer was quite obvious: 
Multiply the given value with a static variable of type ether, which is equal to 1 ETH:

```
 uint256 public myEtherValue = 1 ether;

 Auction[] public auctions;

  function createAuction(address _owner, uint256 _price, string _describtion) public{

    uint256 newPrice = SafeMath.mul(_price, myEtherValue);

    Auction memory _auction = Auction({
      owner: _owner,
      price: newPrice,
      describtion: _describtion
    });

    auctions.push(_auction);
  }

  function getVAlueOfAuction(uint256 x) public returns (uint256 value){
      value = auctions[x].price;
      return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against inputting in ETH. You lose the value of having decimals and run the risk of a user inputting wei and having their price 10^18 times higher than they should. You should accept input as wei and your frontend should perform the conversion from ETH to wei

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that 'Ether' is not a separate variable type. The suffix 'Ether' is just a convenience utility that coverts values in wei to the desired denomination. In your case, prices should be denominated in wei and stored as uint256 variables. On your front-end you can then convert wei price into ether price (1 ether == 1e18 wei). Thus, in your first example, a price of 20 is actually 20 wei which is very tiny amount. [See more here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/units-and-global-variables.html)

Note that this is also how EVM will interpret your input. If you try to send a transaction with a value of 20, you will be actually sending 20 wei so to send 20 ether you actually need to send value = 20,000,000,000,000,000,000